# how to display the contents displayed in another html inside a div of the parent html file

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django, django-templates

The below code shows that when the anchor tag is clicked the content related to that specific title is retrieved and shown in another html page name **doc1.html**.
The link that redirects it to next page in present in this file.
**judge_civil.html file**

```html
<div class="container-middle">
  <div id="limitations" class="tabcontent">
    {% for data in law_data %} {% if data.law_type == 'civil' and
    data.law_category == 'limitations' %}
    <div class="tab">
      <!--<button class="tablinks" onclick="openLawtype(event,'title')">{{data.title}} &nbsp<i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></button>-->
      <a href="{% url 'doc1' data.pk %}" target="_blank">{{data.title}}</a
      ><br /><br />
    </div>

    {% endif %} {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>
```

Here when the link is clicked the content that is associated with {{data.title}} is opened and displayed in a new html file dynamically using the primary key that i have passed along with it. The code in **doc1.html** is below

```html
<p>{{ object.judgements|safe}}</p>
```

But now I want to display this content that is being displayed in doc1.html in the judge_civil.html inside the below :

```html
<div class="container-right"></div>
```

I assume that this can only be done with javascript. I don't know javascript at all so if you can provide me the code to this task it will be really helpfull.

I am also providing the models and viwes and urls code if needed:

**models.py**

```py
class Laws(models.Model):
    date= models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    title= models.CharField(max_length=225, help_text="judgement title")
    judgements= RichTextField(blank=True, null= True)
    law_type= models.CharField(max_length=40, choices= type_of_law)
    law_category= models.CharField(max_length=60, choices= category)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**views.py**

```py
def judge_civil(request):
    law_data= Laws.objects.all().order_by('-date')

    return render(request, 'judge_civil.html', {'law_data': law_data} )


class Doc1DetailView(DetailView):
    model= Laws
    template_name = 'doc1.html'
```

**urls.py**

```py
urlpatterns= [
        path('judge_civil',views.judge_civil, name='judge_civil'),
        path('doc1/<int:pk>/', Doc1DetailView.as_view(), name='doc1' ),
]
```

As I said before I don't know JavaScript at all so it would be appreciated if you write the JavaScript code as exactly what I've to do to achieve this. I've attached a image that should give you a more clear picture of what I want to do.

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can path it in { URL } so when came to file to { judge_civil.html file } , just call **window.location.href** and it will return current { URL }  with data passed to it

Comment: I did not understand. can you please elaborate

Comment: <a href="{% url 'doc1' data.pk {{ object.judgements|safe}} %}" target="_blank">{{data.title}}</a
      ><br /><br />

Comment: so in new file called this { window.location.href }  , then split your content pathed to that URL

Comment: this will target to open in a new blank tab right. i want the contents of {{object.judgement|safe }} in the <div class="container-right">

Comment: so in this file you can called { var last = window.location.href.substring(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, window.location.href
        .length);
    $('.container-right').html(last) }

Comment: I should write this in the javascript?

Comment: ok sir I'll try and let you know if it works

Comment: this code <a href="{% url 'doc1' data.pk {{ object.judgements|safe}} %}" target="_blank">{{data.title}}</a ><br /><br />, is giving syntax error and therefore not wrking

Comment: i'm not sure about syntax but  , I wrote this to figure your problem hope this point was good for you , sorry if it doesn't clear yet

Comment: It's ok, but the code was is not working. However, thanks for trying